# Indifference with utility function

Tags: probability-theory, finance, utility

Let u be the utility function $u(x)=-\frac{x^{-\eta}-1}{\eta},$ with  $x,\eta>0$

Assume that an investor is indifferent between an investment with riskless outcome of 101.005 and a stochastic outcome of K, where $\log(K/100)\sim N(0,05 ;0,16)$. Determine $\eta>0$.

As someone asked for in the comments, my thought process was the following(not sure if any of it is correct): By certainty equivalent
$$u(101,005)=E[u(K)]$$
$$-\frac{101,005^{-\eta}-1}{\eta}=E[-\frac{K^{-\eta}-1}{\eta}]$$
due to linearity
$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[K^{-\eta}]$$
$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[\exp(\log(K^{-\eta}))]$$

$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[\exp(-\eta\log(K))]$$
$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[\exp(-\eta\log(\frac{K}{100}100))]$$
$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[\exp(-\eta\log(\frac{K}{100}100))]$$
$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[\exp(-\eta\log(\frac{K}{100})+\eta\log(100))]$$
$$101,005^{-\eta}=E[\exp(-\eta\log(\frac{K}{100}))]100^{-\eta}$$
using the fact that log(K/100) is normally distributied
$$(\frac{101,005}{100})^{-\eta}=\exp((\eta^2*0,16/2)-\eta*0,05 )$$
$$-\eta \log(1,01005)= \eta^2*0,08-\eta*0,05$$
and with this one has
$$\eta= \frac{0,05-ln(1,01005)}{0,08}$$
which more or less 0,5. I'm honestly not sure though if this is correct. In fact I think that what I did is wrong...

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried using the idea of certainty equivalent but I'm not sure if it makes sense.
What I thought I could do would just be set u(101,005)=E[u(K)]

Comment: Why do you think what you did is wrong?

Comment: If I were to say, I would say that I'm more or less not confident if it is right and wanted to have some feedback, as I'm still getting used to certainty equivalent.